# Constructing a corrupt dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I accidently, I constructed a corrupt Dataframe. However, I do not know why it was allowed such construction, do you have any idea, is it a bug?

Here, how you can produce a corrupt dataframe (look at "lv4" column - 9 instances of "Agree" instead of 8, as it happens with the labels in lv1-lv8 columns except lv4 column):

```
 data_names<- structure(list(
            vars = c("self esteem", "self image", "peers esteem", "family esteem", "public esteem", "knowledge esteem", "esteem on goods", "partner's esteem"),
                   lv1 = c("absolutely disagree (5)", "absolutely disagree (5)", "absolutely disagree (5)", "absolutely disagree (5)", "absolutely disagree (5)", "absolutely disagree (5)", "absolutely disagree (5)", "absolutely disagree (5)"),
                   lv2 = c("disagree (4)", "disagree (4)", "disagree (4)", "disagree (4)", "disagree (4)", "disagree (4)", "disagree (4)", "disagree (4)"),
                   lv3 = c("neutral (3)", "neutral (3)", "neutral (3)", "neutral (3)", "neutral (3)", "neutral (3)", "neutral (3)", "neutral (3)"),
                   lv4 = c("agree (2)", "agree (2)", "agree (2)", "agree (2)", "agree (2)", "agree (2)", "agree (2)", "agree (2)", "agree (2)"),
                   lv5 = c("absolutely agree (1)", "absolutely agree (1)", "absolutely agree (1)", "absolutely agree (1)", "absolutely agree (1)", "absolutely agree (1)", "absolutely agree (1)", "absolutely agree (1)"),
                   lv6 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_),
                   lv7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_),
                   lv8 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)),
                   .Names = c("vars", "lv1", "lv2", "lv3", "lv4", "lv5", "lv6", "lv7", "lv8"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the error messages that show something like this:

```
t(data_names):
Error in as.matrix.data.frame(x) : 
  dims [product 72] do not match the length of object [73]

t(data_names["lv4"]):
Error in as.matrix.data.frame(x) : 
  dims [product 8] do not match the length of object [9]

table(data_names):
Error in table(data_names) : all arguments must have the same length

table(data_names["lv4"]):

agree (2)
        9 

table(data_names["lv3"]):
neutral (3) 
          8
```

while:

```
dim(data_names["lv4"]):
[1] 8 1

dim(data_names["lv3"]):
[1] 8 1
```

Can you suggest anything why such corrupted dataframes can be constructed and some function fail on their manipulation? structure is not responsible to provide some error messages? Why dim function fail to report the right dimensions of the "lv4" column while table function succeed to do so?

Comment: If you don't use the proper constructor function you shouldn't be surprised that you don't get all the checks.

Comment: Which is the proper constructor function for dataframes?

Comment: In this case, it would be `tibble::data_frame`.

Comment: data.frame obviously. Although you are creating not only a data.frame. Don't know what constructor from the tidyverse you should use since I don't use Hadley's data.frame extensions.